# Import big file into mysql, on a Heroku app

Tags: php, mysql, heroku, import, timeout

I need some help.

I have an php app on Heroku. In this app, there's a form that upload an csv file, to be imported on Mysql(cleardb).

The problem it's, that the file it's large (will always be large), and the function it's taking too much time to finish (about 90 seconds). The timeout on heroku it's 30 seconds, and there's no way to change that.

I tried to use Heroku Scheduler (like cron), but the minimal frequency it's 10 minutes, and a script that can take 90 seconds, using this scheduler, will take 30 minutes, because as i said, the timeout of heroku it's 30 seconds.

Well, what can i do? there's an alternative scheduler?

Example of the import:

**CSV**

```
name,productName,points,categoryName,coordName,date
```

**MYSQL**

[users]

```
userID
userName
categoryID
coordID
```

[products]

```
productID
productName
```

[coords]

```
coordID
coordName
```

[categories]

```
categoryID
categoryName
```

[points]

```
pointID
productID
userID
value
```

in all tables, i need to make a select to see if the category, coord, etc, already exists. If exists, return id, if not, insert a new line.

I dont think that there's a way to decrease time execution time. I'm trying to find a way to decrease the schedule to 2 minutes, 3 minutes, etc. So, in about 10 minutes, all lines will be imported.

thanks!

Comment: a) Is the data in the csv file adding, updating or (completely) replacing exisiting data in the database? b) Are there constraints/indices on the table you're importing the data into? Would it be possible to disable them temporarily for the import? c) Have you looked into [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)? (_sometimes_ it's viable). d) In general: Have you worked through https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html and/or https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-myisam-bulk-data-loading.html?

Comment: a) just adding. But i need to make a lot of selects in about 5 tables, to make sure that there's no duplicate data.
b) yeah, it's possible, will try to make that and see if helps.
c) dont think it helps, because, what's taking more time it's probally the selects i need to make, to be sure that the data it's correct.

i can try to decrease this time, changing the code a little, but i doubt that will do all in just 30 seconds.

Comment: I guess right now you're doing those SELECTs for each single record you're importing? a) you can look into prepared+parametrized statements to speed things up a bit. b) WOuld it be possible to import all the data in one bulk operation into a (temporary) table and then perform the queries for the "real import™" in one go, e.g. via [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)?

Comment: question updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would *start* with (because it's relatively simple/quick to implement and should give you a reference point and some wiggle room for further tests in a short period of time):

Import all the data as-is into a temporary table (if the server's RAM allow you can also try the [memory engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-storage-engine.html)).
Then, *after* the data has been imported, create the indices needed for the following queries (and check via [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) or any other tool that shows you if and how the indices are used):

- query all the categories that are in the temporary table but *not* in your live data tables

  - create those categories in the live tables.
- query all coords that are in the temporary table but not in your live data tables.

  - create those coords in the live tables.
- you get the idea ...repeat for all necessary data.
- then just import the data from the temp table into the live tables via [INSERT...SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) queries. Think about what kind of transaction/locking you will need for this. It *might* be that the order of queries will make a difference. But if you're only adding data, I assume that a rather low isolation level should do... not sure though. But maybe that's not your concern right now?